# How to delete all the logs using gcloud command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-shell

I tried the following [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/logs/delete):

```sh
gcloud logging logs delete
```

but it is asking log name

> ERROR: (gcloud.logging.logs.delete) argument LOG_NAME: Must be specified.

I want to get all the logs to be deleted which are default.

Comment: I do not recommend deleting logs.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't delete all logs.

Comment: Thanks, I am practicing GCP hence deleting unwanted logs.

Answer (score 6):

Your question would benefit from showing some attempt to solve this problem for yourself.

See [`gcloud logging logs delete`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/logs/delete)

It requires a `LOG_NAME` as provided by e.g. [`gcloud logging logs list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/logs/list).

Since `logs list` returns a simple list of logs if you wanted to delete existing (!) log entries for all logs in a specific project, you could:

**Use the following at your own risk**
**it will irrecoverably delete every existing log entry in every log in the current project**

```sh
PROJECT="[[YOUR-PROJECT]]"

LOGS=$(\
  gcloud logging log list \
  --project=${PROJECT}

for LOG in ${LOGS}
do
  gcloud logging logs delete ${LOG} \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --quiet
done
```

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin, I was looking for a direct command, but its not available. This script will help!